# Query to delete duplicate records by keeping original in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is the table.

```
Id.           Name
1               A
1               A
2               B
2               C
1               A
2               B
2               D
```

The output should be

```
Id.           Name
1               A
2               B
2               C
2               D
```

Comment: what did you try to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

please try

```
Select distinct id, name 
from <name of you table>
order by name
```

Check <kbd>[this](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-select-distinct/)</kbd> link.

Answer (score 2):

Sample data:

```
create table demo (id, name) as
select 1, 'A' from dual union all
select 1, 'A' from dual union all
select 2, 'B' from dual union all
select 2, 'C' from dual union all
select 1, 'A' from dual union all
select 2, 'B' from dual union all
select 2, 'D' from dual;

select * from demo order by 1,2;

        ID NAME
---------- ------------------------------
         1 A
         1 A
         1 A
         2 B
         2 B
         2 C
         2 D

7 rows selected
```

Delete all but the first row in each (id, name) group:

```
delete demo where rowid in
( select lag(rowid) over (partition by id, name order by null) from demo );

3 rows deleted

select * from demo order by 1,2

        ID N
---------- -
         1 A
         2 B
         2 C
         2 D

4 rows selected.
```